# IntellIJ editor doesn't appear

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated my IntellIJ install to the latest version (11.1.4) and now the Editor window doesn't appear. Double-clicking on the file, jump-to-source, nothing happens. No error message, it just doesn't appear. If I double-click on an xml layout file the preview window works, but no Editor window. Have installed and reinstalled; went back to an earlier version and it doesn't work there either. I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Update: Editor works if I create a new project. 
Update 2: idea.log file includes this (I don't know what ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData is):

```
2012-11-04 20:40:52,481 [   2677]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:52,481 [   2677]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:52,482 [   2678]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:52,482 [   2678]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:52,564 [   2760]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 76 application components initialized in 1285 ms 
2012-11-04 20:40:52,575 [   2771]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/customization.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:52,575 [   2771]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/customization.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:52,674 [   2870]   INFO - ij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeRootPane - App initialization took 3385 ms 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,136 [   3332]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,138 [   3334]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,253 [   3449]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/dynamic.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,253 [   3449]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/dynamic.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,280 [   3476]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - 1 paths checked, 0 mapped, 202 mks 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,366 [   3562]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 137 project components initialized in 403 ms 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,563 [   3759]   INFO - .module.impl.ModuleManagerImpl - 4 modules loaded in 197 ms 
2012-11-04 20:40:53,625 [   3821]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - 6 paths checked, 0 mapped, 150 mks 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,187 [   4383]   INFO - .roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl - Directory index initialized in 271 ms, indexed 1611 directories 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,207 [   4403]   INFO - pl.PushedFilePropertiesUpdater - File properties pushed in 18 ms 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,237 [   4433]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/plainTextFiles.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,237 [   4433]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/plainTextFiles.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,246 [   4442]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/gant_config.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,246 [   4442]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/gant_config.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,253 [   4449]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/gradle.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:54,253 [   4449]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/gradle.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:55,855 [   6051]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/IntelliLang.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:55,855 [   6051]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/IntelliLang.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:56,995 [   7191]   INFO - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - splitter 
2012-11-04 20:40:56,996 [   7192]   INFO - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - splitter 
2012-11-04 20:40:57,233 [   7429]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/codeStyleSettings.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:57,233 [   7429]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/codeStyleSettings.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:57,234 [   7430]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/projectCodeStyle.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:57,234 [   7430]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/projectCodeStyle.xml 
2012-11-04 20:40:58,145 [   8341]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 3911 ms 
2012-11-04 20:40:58,146 [   8342]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2012-11-04 20:40:58,146 [   8342]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms 
2012-11-04 20:40:58,362 [   8558]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/fileColors.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:40:58,362 [   8558]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/fileColors.xml 
2012-11-04 20:41:00,420 [  10616]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - For input string: "20.0.1" 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20.0.1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.parsePackageRevision(AndroidSdkData.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.<init>(AndroidSdkData.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.parse(AndroidSdkData.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.addResourceFolderToSdkRootsIfNecessary(AndroidFacet.java:532)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.access$500(AndroidFacet.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet$3.run(AndroidFacet.java:440)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$6.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:230)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:203)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$100(StartupManagerImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$4.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.updateFinished(DumbServiceImpl.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.access$1000(DumbServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl$IndexUpdateRunnable$1$3.run(DumbServiceImpl.java:363)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:672)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:699)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:538)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:420)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:378)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
2012-11-04 20:41:00,459 [  10655]   INFO - ins.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData - For input string: "20.0.1" 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20.0.1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.parsePackageRevision(AndroidSdkData.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.<init>(AndroidSdkData.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.parse(AndroidSdkData.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.addResourceFolderToSdkRootsIfNecessary(AndroidFacet.java:532)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet.access$500(AndroidFacet.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet$3.run(AndroidFacet.java:440)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$6.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:230)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivities(StartupManagerImpl.java:203)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.access$100(StartupManagerImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl$4.run(StartupManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.updateFinished(DumbServiceImpl.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.access$1000(DumbServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl$IndexUpdateRunnable$1$3.run(DumbServiceImpl.java:363)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:672)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:699)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:538)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:420)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:378)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
2012-11-04 20:41:01,305 [  11501]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 8374 ms 
2012-11-04 20:41:01,719 [  11915]   INFO - dom.attrs.AttributeDefinitions - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2012-11-04 20:41:07,522 [  17718]   INFO - roid.compiler.tools.AndroidApt - [/Users/neveu/Dev/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/aapt] [package] [-m] [--non-constant-id] [-J] [/private/var/folders/xb/hg6cdxt51rs8lylmmjw0fk8m0000gp/T/android_apt_autogeneration6157451500950136901tmp] [-M] [/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/3rdParty/facebook/AndroidManifest.xml] [-S] [/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/3rdParty/facebook/res] [-I] [/Users/neveu/Dev/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-14/android.jar] 
2012-11-04 20:41:08,706 [  18902]   INFO - roid.compiler.tools.AndroidApt - [/Users/neveu/Dev/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/aapt] [package] [-m] [-J] [/private/var/folders/xb/hg6cdxt51rs8lylmmjw0fk8m0000gp/T/android_apt_autogeneration3143184519400737414tmp] [-M] [/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/AndroidManifest.xml] [-S] [/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/res] [-I] [/Users/neveu/Dev/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-15/android.jar] 
2012-11-04 20:41:08,763 [  18959]   INFO - roid.compiler.tools.AndroidIdl - [/Users/neveu/Dev/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/aidl] [-p/Users/neveu/Dev/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-15/framework.aidl] [-I/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/magic/src] [-I/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/src] [-I/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/3rdParty/Tapjoy] [-I/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/gen] [/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/src/com/android/vending/billing/IMarketBillingService.aidl] [/Users/neveu/Dev/magic_android/gen/com/android/vending/billing/IMarketBillingService.java] 
2012-11-04 20:41:14,004 [  24200]   INFO - dom.attrs.AttributeDefinitions - Found tag with unknown parent: AndroidManifest.AndroidManifestCompatibleScreens 
2012-11-04 20:41:18,781 [  28977]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/cachedDictionary.xml file is null 
2012-11-04 20:41:18,782 [  28978]   INFO - .impl.stores.XmlElementStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/cachedDictionary.xml
```

Comment: I ended up creating a new project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of this kind of problems the first thing to check is **idea.log** file (`Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`).

It may help to understand what is going wrong and in some cases you'll be able to identify the root case from the logged exception (like corrupted caches or some incompatible plug-in).

`File` | **Invalidate Caches** is the next thing to try. If it doesn't fix the problem, go to the [Plugins settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-installing-and-uninstalling-plugins-from-a-repository.html) and disable/uninstall all the non-bundled plug-ins (if you have any).

Didn't help? If work needs to be done urgently and you have no time to investigate further, rename/delete [IDEA folders](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) (config, caches, plugins) to start with all the defaults and create a new project.

Want to preserve the settings and project files? [Contact support](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA) with `idea.log` to get it resolved.